# How can I create an observable like the one returned by defer using Observable.create?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I'm trying to create an observable with behavior similar to what is returned by `defer`, but using `create` method. So I try:

```
const obs = Observable.create(function(observer) {
   from(fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(console.log('fetch done'))).subscribe(observer)
})

setTimeout(()=>obs.subscribe((resp)=>console.log(resp.statusText)), 5000)
```

But when I run it in `node` It just prints "fetch done" (on subscription, after 5 seconds as expected) but waits forever there.

When I wrap the `from(..)` in `setImmediate()` or `setTimeout(,0)`, then sometimes it prints both messages ("Fetch done", "OK") and exits and **sometimes it only prints "fetch done" and waits forever.**

code:

```
const obs = Observable.create(function(observer) {
    setTimeout(()=>from(fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(console.log('fetch done'))).subscribe(observer), 0)
})

setTimeout(()=>obs.subscribe((resp)=>console.log(resp.statusText)), 5000)
```

Why this happens? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promise.then takes a callback function, and you need to return the argument to chain it, so it becomes `then(result => { console.log('fetch done', result); return result; })`

Comment: That's correct! After fixing this, there is no need to use `setTimeout`/`setImmediate`.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that `Observable.create` is deprecated and you should use just `new Observable()`:

When creating Observables like this you have access to `observer` object where you can call `next()` and `complete()` so in your case it would be like this:

```
new Observable(observer => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(response => {
    observer.next(response);
    observer.complete();
  });
});
```

I think this should work as well:

```
new Observable(observer => {
  const sub =  from(fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).subscribe(observer);
  // Return tear-down function so you can abort request.
  return () => sub.unsubscribe();
});
```

Obviously, this is over complicated and if you just want to wrap a Promise with Observable you can use just `from()`.